# custom library and helper not being called in database.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 3.1.2.  I have a custom library and helper which i have auto loaded in autoload.php.

But all of these functions from helper and library not being called when I use these in `database.php` or in `hooks` (pre_controller) **BUT SYSTEM'S LIBRARIES WORKS FINE THERE LIKE `session`, `router` etc etc**

database.php

```
$CI = & get_instance();
echo $CI->nuts_lib->enc($_REQUEST['clid']);
return;
```

It shows following error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: My_controller::$nuts_lib
>
> Filename: config/database.php
>
> Line Number: 76
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\application\config\database.php Line:
>   76 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\application\controllers\My_controller.php
>   Line: 18 Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\index.php Line: 280 Function:
>   require_once

I have tried through hooks still not worked. Help Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I can use native/system libraries direct in `database.php` and I have placed my encryption related code there. Now its working

Answer (score -2):

See the flow of CI, Libraries are loaded before Database/Models

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html